# Is this a valid way to return a two-dimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following `C`-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mat1[2][4] = {
    {9, 10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15, 16}
};

int (*(transpose)(int matrix[][4]))[2] {
    static int mat[4][2];
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("I am the function transpose()\nand I'm transposing 2x4 matrices.\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            mat[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

int main() {
    int (*mat_transpose)[2];
    int i;
    int j;
    mat_transpose = transpose(mat1);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("mat_transpose[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat_transpose[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function `transpose()` returns a two-dimensional array (Or rather a pointer to an array of pointers, I guess.). Is this a valid way to achieve this? Looking through various Stackoverflow questions it seems like there is no standard way of doing this but rather a great many. Is there some standard regarding returning two- or multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: what exactly is `int (*(transpose)(int matrix[][4]))[2]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390541/correct-way-to-return-two-dimensional-array-from-a-function-c

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is a pointer to a 2 element array which in itself is composed of 4 elements.

Comment: The general advice is to avoid 2 dimensional array in C (so use `arr1d[i*width+j]` instead of `arr2d[i][j]`....). You might want to have some [flexible array member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: @SouravGhosh; It declares `transpose` as a function that expects an argument of type `int (*)[2]` and returns a pointer to `int [2]`. BTW, +1 to the question for good understanding of pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid way to return a two-dimensional array?

Yes. Returning a pointer to `static` local variable is valid.  One thing I would suggest is that you can `typedef` that return type

```
typedef matx[2];  

matx *transpose(int matrix[][4])){ /* Function body */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to allocate the array in the caller function, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transpose(int rows, int columns,
        int matrix[rows][columns], int mat[columns][rows])
{
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("I am the function transpose()\n");
    printf("And I'm transposing 2x4 matrices.\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            mat[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int mat1[2][4] =
    {
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };
    int mat_transpose[4][2];
    int i;
    int j;

    transpose(2, 4, mat1, mat_transpose);
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            printf("mat_transpose[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat_transpose[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it makes absolutely no sense to make `mat1` a global variable when you will pass it as a parameter anyway.

Comment: `int matrix[rows][columns]` isn't valid C. Try `int matrix[/*rows*/][/*columns*/]`

Comment: @PeterSchneider; C99 addes this feature and yes you can pass it to a function.

Comment: @PeterSchneider the link you give starts with this _Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99_.

Comment: Hm, I see -- in the n1570 draft there are examples for that in 6.7.6.2/10, Example 4. Fascinating (raising eye brow).

Comment: @iharob I had read that sentence ;-) -- thought VLAs as arguments are gcc specific though.

Answer (score 0):

You just should have your function

```
    int **transpose(int **matrix, int row, int columns)
    {
       int **mat;

       // Malloc you array, copy what you need and return it
       ...
    }
```

Row and columns being the number of rows and column of `int **matrix`

Answer (score 0):

It is valid because it do what it claims to do but I guess you know that already.

I don't think there is such things as standards for returning n-dimensional arrays, only best practices.

The only thing I can say about your function is that it lacks genericity (you only process 2*4 Matrixes) but maybe that was not your goal.