# Why does this program segfault when returning a pointer to a local static variable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is related to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054085/is-this-a-valid-way-to-return-a-two-dimensional-array) of mine. I tried expanding the code a little bit and to play around with different ways of returning pointers to local static variables, especially returning two-dimensional arrays. (This is seriously just to understand how pointers to arrays work and how they behave in function environments. It has not even the slightest intent of returning arrays the smart way using `struct`s.) I wrote two functions both transpose matrices. The function `transpose()` only transposes 2x4-matrices and  the function `transpose_generic()` is supposed to transpose matrices of arbitrary size. There is no real use to them. After I have declared and defined the functions I call them from `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){}`. The two matrices that have been transposed are supposed to be printed to `stdout` in a simple for-loop. And here is something I don't understand. Depending on whether I declare the matrices that are supposed to be transposed as global or local variables I get a segfault or "clean" exit. I can also prevent the compiled program from segfaulting by using a for loop after the for loop that prints the transposed matrices to `stdout`. But the for-loop needs to use a new index. I'm sure I'm missing something very basic but I cannot figure this out on my own. Even after extensive internet searching I'm still puzzled. So maybe someone can enlighten me. Here is the code:

### Will segfault

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mat1[2][4] = {
    {9, 10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15, 16}
};

int mat2[2][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8}
};

typedef matx[2];
matx *transpose(int matrix[][4]);

typedef maty[];
maty *transpose_generic(int nrow, int ncol, int matrix1[nrow][ncol], int matrix2[nrow][ncol]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* This may need a little bit of clarification. Here we want to declare a
     * pointer to an array and we need the round brackets () for this. If we
     * were simply to write *mat_transpose[2] we would declare an array of
     * pointers since [] has higher precedence than *. */
    int (*mat_transpose)[2];

    int tmat[2][4];
    int i;
    int j;

    mat_transpose = transpose(mat1);
    transpose_generic(2, 4, mat2, tmat);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("mat_transpose[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat_transpose[i][j]);
            printf("tmat[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tmat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

matx *transpose(int matrix[][4]) {
    static int mat[4][2];
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Transpose a 2x4 matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            mat[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

maty *transpose_generic(int nrow, int ncol,
                        int matrix1[nrow][ncol],
                        int matrix2[nrow][ncol]) {
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Transpose a matrix\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
            matrix2[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }
    return matrix2;
}
```

### Will exit clean

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef matx[2];
matx *transpose(int matrix[][4]);

typedef maty[];
maty *transpose_generic(int nrow, int ncol, int matrix1[nrow][ncol], int matrix2[nrow][ncol]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int mat1[2][4] = {
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };

    int mat2[2][4] = {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8}
    };


    /* This may need a little bit of clarification. Here we want to declare a
     * pointer to an array and we need the round brackets () for this. If we
     * were simply to write *mat_transpose[2] we would declare an array of
     * pointers since [] has higher precedence than *. */
    int (*mat_transpose)[2];

    int tmat[2][4];
    int i;
    int j;

    mat_transpose = transpose(mat1);
    transpose_generic(2, 4, mat2, tmat);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("mat_transpose[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat_transpose[i][j]);
            printf("tmat[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tmat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

matx *transpose(int matrix[][4]) {
    static int mat[4][2];
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Transpose a 2x4 matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            mat[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

maty *transpose_generic(int nrow, int ncol,
        int matrix1[nrow][ncol],
        int matrix2[nrow][ncol]) {
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Transpose a matrix\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
            matrix2[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }
    return matrix2;
}
```

### Will exit clean

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mat1[2][4] = {
    {9, 10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15, 16}
};

int mat2[2][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8}
};

typedef matx[2];
matx *transpose(int matrix[][4]);

typedef maty[];
maty *transpose_generic(int nrow, int ncol, int matrix1[nrow][ncol], int matrix2[nrow][ncol]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* This may need a little bit of clarification. Here we want to declare a
     * pointer to an array and we need the round brackets () for this. If we
     * were simply to write *mat_transpose[2] we would declare an array of
     * pointers since [] has higher precedence than *. */
    int (*mat_transpose)[2];

    int tmat[2][4];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

    mat_transpose = transpose(mat1);
    transpose_generic(2, 4, mat2, tmat);

    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            printf("mat_transpose[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, mat_transpose[i][j]);
            printf("tmat[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tmat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
        printf("H");
    }
    return 0;
}

matx *transpose(int matrix[][4]) {
    static int mat[4][2];
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Transpose a 2x4 matrix\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            mat[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}

maty *transpose_generic(int nrow, int ncol,
        int matrix1[nrow][ncol],
        int matrix2[nrow][ncol]) {
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Transpose a matrix\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ncol; j++) {
            matrix2[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }
    return matrix2;
}
```

Comment: The "clean exit" is just a random consequence here. If you declare some other variables, write a little bit different code or switch a compiler, this behaviour may change. This is why it is called "undefined behaviour".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line,

```
        printf("tmat[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, tmat[i][j]);
```

When `i>1` your code causes undefined behaviour since you `tmat` is declared as `int tmat[2][4];`.

The same problem exists in all three code snippets and you just happen to get segfault only for the first one. This is not at all related to whether you return a a pointer to a function scoped `static` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy. If it would be appropriate to curse here, I would. I totally missed this!