# How to return a statically allocated two-dimensional array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, return-type, function-declaration

I have the following code in `spbox.c`:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct {
    bool initialized;
    uint32_t Spbox[8][64]; // Combined S and P boxes
} spboxState;

static spboxState stateInstance;

uint32_t ** desGetSpbox(void) {
    if (!(stateInstance.initialized)) {
        // TODO: Compute data to populate Spbox array
        stateInstance.initialized = true;
    }
    return stateInstance.Spbox;
}
```

I compile it:

```
clang -c spbox.c
```

I get a warning about incompatible pointer return types:

```
spbox.c:16:9: warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'uint32_t [8][64]' from a function with result type 'uint32_t **' (aka 'unsigned int **') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        return stateInstance.Spbox;
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

How do I change my code to make the warning go away? It is saying that `uint32_t **` isn't compatible with `uint32_t [8][64]`. But if I try to make the later the return type, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [correct way to return two dimensional array from a function c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390541/correct-way-to-return-two-dimensional-array-from-a-function-c)

Comment: @RobertHarvey A lot of stuff in that question doesn't seem relevant. It says you can't return an array declared in a function because it will be deallocated when the function exits; that's not what I'm doing. There is the suggestion to return a pointer to a structure. I could do that, but why can't I just return a pointer to the array element of the structure?

Comment: `why can't I just return a pointer to the array element of the structure?` -- You can, if you set its type properly.  Otherwise, C has no idea what the shape of the array is.  See the answer below.

Comment: You can also simply return a void pointer, if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What I needed was somebody to teach me the (rather convoluted) syntax for a function returning a pointer to an array element (even a multi-dimensional one). Vlad's answer does that. I can't find that in that other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not return an array. But you may return a pointer to an array or its first element.

For example

```
uint32_t ( * desGetSpbox(void) )[8][64] {
    if (!(stateInstance.initialized)) {
        // TODO: Compute data to populate Spbox array
        stateInstance.initialized = true;
    }
    return &stateInstance.Spbox;
}
```

Or

```
uint32_t ( * desGetSpbox(void) )[64] {
    if (!(stateInstance.initialized)) {
        // TODO: Compute data to populate Spbox array
        stateInstance.initialized = true;
    }
    return stateInstance.Spbox;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

enum { M = 8, N = 64 };

typedef struct {
    bool initialized;
    uint32_t Spbox[M][N]; // Combined S and P boxes
} spboxState;

static spboxState stateInstance;

uint32_t ( *desGetSpbox1( void ) )[M][N] 
{
    stateInstance.Spbox[0][0] = 10;
    return &stateInstance.Spbox;
}

uint32_t ( *desGetSpbox2( void ) )[N] 
{
    stateInstance.Spbox[0][0] = 10;
    return stateInstance.Spbox;
}


int main(void) 
{
    uint32_t ( *p1 )[M][N] = desGetSpbox1();
    
    printf( "%" PRIu32 "\n", ( *p1 )[0][0] );

    uint32_t ( *p2 )[N] = desGetSpbox2();
    
    printf( "%" PRIu32 "\n", ( *p2 )[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
10
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first example is what I wanted to do, I just didn't know the (rather convoluted!) syntax. Although thinking about it, maybe I should use a typedef to make it clearer: `typedef uint32_t spbox_t[8][64];`. Then I can just do `spbox_t *desGetSpbox(void) {`. That's equivalent to your first example, right? If so I might do that because it looks a bit clearer.

Comment: @SimonKissane Yes you can introduce a typedef.